# How to update DOM elements using angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is my angular code:

```
<div ng-repeat="s in doc.Summaries">
  <a href="#" ng-click="doc.summaryIdShown = s.index">
    {{s.SummaryState}}: {{s.StopLightColor}}, {{s.LevelOfEvidence}} - {{s.UserName}} - {{s.UpdateTimeStamp | date}}
  </a>
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
```

In the code I am displaying a link for every version (s in doc.Summaries) of a document. Then, when a user clicks on the link I update my model variable "summaryIdShown" and the version being presented on the side is updated. The issue is: I would like to update these links so that the link corresponding to the version being shown so that it looks different. How would I do that?

I thought about writing a custom directive but I am having trouble with the implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: update the class of the item when clicked. Using ng-class would be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `ng-class` directive, pass in an object which has a class name you want to add and a boolean condition which it should check:

```
<div ng-repeat="s in doc.Summaries">
    <a href="#" ng-click="doc.summaryIdShown = s.index" ng-class="{'green': doc.summaryIdShown === s.index}">
         {{s.SummaryState}}: {{s.StopLightColor}}, {{s.LevelOfEvidence}} - {{s.UserName}} - {{s.UpdateTimeStamp | date}}
    </a>
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.green {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: you also have other options like ng-style, but I don't recommend that. ng-options is the best one to use.